# ReferenceError: React is not defined - Migrating from CRA to Vite and NX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, nrwl-nx

I'm currently in the process of migrating a create-react-app (CRA - v4) monorepo Webpack setup to an NX Monorepo powered by Vite.

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to solve the typical

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

This happens whenever a file doesn't import React directly, but has a named import from it, such as:

```js
import { memo } from 'react';
```

I've run the linter that removed all the `import React` statements, and it'd be daunting to through hundreds and hundreds of files to add it again.

Here's more info:

- I believe I'm using the newest JSX transform and React 17.
- nx-plugin-vite: ^1.1.0
- vite: ^2.7.1
- vite-tsconfig-paths: ^3.3.17
- vite-plugin-eslint: ^1.3.0
- @vitejs/plugin-react: ^1.1.3
- @nrwl/react": 13.2.4,
  (More in the package.json)

I've also read and read again several sources across GitHub, SO, and the web and haven't found anything

- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/migrating-a-150k-loc-codebase-to-vite-and-esbuild-how-part-2-3-91b0b873f388
- https://github.com/nordcloud/pat-frontend-template/blob/master/docs/CRA_MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#update-tsconfig-path-aliasing-included
- https://darekkay.com/blog/create-react-app-to-vite/

Here's my `vite.config.ts`

```
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), eslintPlugin(), react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      stream: 'stream-browserify',
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
  },
});
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

And the base tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@schon/legacy-components/*": ["apps/app/src/components/*"],
      "@schon/graphql/*": ["apps/app/src/graphql/*"],
      "@schon/hooks/*": ["libs/components/src/hooks/*"],
      "@schon/components/*": ["libs/components/src/ad/*"],
      "@schon/legacy-components2/*": ["libs/components/src/stories/*"],
      "@schon/theme": ["libs/components/src/styles/index.ts"],
      "@schon/typings": ["libs/components/src/typings/index.ts"],
      "@schon/utils": ["libs/components/src/utils/index.ts"],
      "~/*": ["apps/app/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

project.json:

```json
{
  "root": "apps/app",
  "projectType": "application",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/app/src",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "serve": {
      "executor": "nx-plugin-vite:serve",
      "options": {
        "configFile": "apps/app/vite.config.ts",
        "port": 3001,
        "host": false,
        "https": false
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "executor": "nx-plugin-vite:preview",
      "options": {
        "configFile": "apps/app/vite.config.ts"
      }
    },
    "build": {
      "executor": "nx-plugin-vite:build",
      "options": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "configFile": "apps/app/vite.config.ts",
        "watch": false,
        "write": true,
        "emitAtRootLevel": false,
        "manifest": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's one of the files that is giving me problems (Throws me the React is not defined):
(This one comes from a component repo that is being handled by storybook)

```
import { memo } from 'react';
import { Container as MaterialContainer } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ThemeSpecs } from '../../../styles/theme';

type ContainerProps = {
  children?:
    | JSX.Element
    | JSX.Element[]
    | React.ReactNode
    | React.ReactChildren;
  className?: string;
};

/**
 * Jose decided to wrap this up, in case we needed to apply a general styling to the container
 * itself, and avoid repeating it in every other component.
 */
const Component: React.FC<ContainerProps> = (props) => (
  <MaterialContainer
    className={props.className}
    fixed
    style={{ paddingTop: ThemeSpecs.container.paddingTop }}
  >
    {props.children!}
  </MaterialContainer>
);

type withContainerProps = {};

/**
 * This is a HOC so we can use this to Containerize the imports back
 * at root. This way we can choose which routes use Containers
 * and which don't.
 */

export const withContainer = <P extends object>(
  ComponentToContainer: React.ComponentType<P>
) =>
  class WithContainer extends React.PureComponent<P & withContainerProps> {
    render() {
      return (
        <Container>
          <ComponentToContainer {...this.props} />
        </Container>
      );
    }
  };

export const Container = memo(Component) as typeof Component;
```

package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.6",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.8.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.44.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "@material-table/core": "^4.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.12.1",
    "@nivo/calendar": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/tooltip": "^0.74.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.4",
    "auth0-js": "^9.18.0",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^3.0.7",
    "aws-appsync-subscription-link": "^3.0.9",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1046.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3-array": "^3.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "formik-persist": "^1.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^5.4.5",
    "fraql": "^1.2.1",
    "graphql": "^16.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "immer": "^9.0.7",
    "linkifyjs": "^3.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "logrocket": "^2.1.2",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "msw": "^0.36.3",
    "password-validator": "^5.2.1",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "^0.11.5",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-google-docs-viewer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.5",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.0.1",
    "react-prerendered-component": "^1.2.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "suneditor": "^2.41.3",
    "suneditor-react": "^3.3.1",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.1",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "use-debounce": "^7.0.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validate-password": "^1.0.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.4",
    "@babel/core": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.12.13",
    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/node": "^13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "^13.3.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "^13.2.4",
    "@nxext/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@snowpack/plugin-dotenv": "^2.2.0",
    "@snowpack/plugin-react-refresh": "^2.5.0",
    "@snowpack/plugin-typescript": "^1.2.1",
    "@snowpack/web-test-runner-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/react": "~6.3.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.14.5",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.21",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/react": "17.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9",
    "@types/react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/snowpack-env": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/tiny-slider-react": "^0.3.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.33.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.1.3",
    "@web/test-runner": "^0.13.17",
    "babel-jest": "27.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "jest": "27.2.3",
    "nx-plugin-snowpack": "^0.3.0",
    "nx-plugin-vite": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "snowpack": "^3.8.8",
    "storybook-theme-toggle": "^0.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.7.1",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.3.0",
    "vite-preset-react": "^2.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.3.17"
  }
}
```

The nx.json:

```json
{
  "npmScope": "schon",
  "affected": {
    "defaultBase": "main"
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/react"
  },
  "implicitDependencies": {
    "package.json": {
      "dependencies": "*",
      "devDependencies": "*"
    },
    ".eslintrc.json": "*"
  },
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "@nrwl/nx-cloud",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"],
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDependencies": {
    "build": [
      {
        "target": "build",
        "projects": "dependencies"
      }
    ]
  },
  "generators": {
    "@nrwl/react": {
      "application": {
        "style": "css",
        "linter": "eslint",
        "babel": true
      },
      "component": {
        "style": "css"
      },
      "library": {
        "style": "css",
        "linter": "eslint"
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app"
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I also received `ReferenceError: React is not defined` when porting my app from create-react-app to vite. The issue stemmed from CRA using the new jsx runtime to auto-import React into jsx files.

Vite doesn't use the new jsx runtime by default but you can easily add it by installing the [`@vitejs/plugin-react`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-react):

```bash
# install the plugin
yarn add @vitejs/plugin-react
```

...and then updating `vite.config.js`:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Note: `@vitejs/plugin-react` also includes `react-refresh` so you should be able to remove `@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh` if you're using it.

Comment: Thanks!!! I did include it in the question! (Please double check!). The problem was that I was using React.Fragment (directly calling React), when in fact I either needed to have it in scope or destruct the fragment.

Comment: For me this isn't working, but I only get the error on builds.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Apparently there was a moment in which I stripped out all of the `import React` statements. But beware, you can't just blindly remove it if you don't destruct Children, Fragment, or others.

For example:

if you have:

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';

const MyElem = () => {
  const myMemo = useMemo(() => {}, []);
  return (
       <React.Fragment>
       </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

and you remove `React`, you will have the dependency `Fragment` lingering around.

You will have to import it, or destruct the `Fragment`

Meaning, that you will have to do this:

```
import {Fragment, memo} from 'react';

const MyElem = () => {
  const myMemo = useMemo(() => {}, []);
  return (
       <Fragment>
       </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution. As one of the developers of @nxext. I can confirm standard introduce by NX was to auto inject React using tsconfig `"jsx": "react-jsx",` As a result we followed this standard for the vite builder. 

If people want to manually import react then you can just remove JSX line from tsconfig

Comment: Oooooohhhh. Glad to know that Jordan!! Thank you so much. Nx has been incredible! Appreciate all the hard work put by the team!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem. For new apps and React 17 projects onwards, using jsxRuntime: 'automatic' is recommended as it provides many benefits in terms of code size and performance. However, if you are working on an old project or want to keep the classic syntax, you can use jsxRuntime: 'classic' or not use a jsxRuntime configuration if you want to keep the defaults.

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxRuntime: 'automatic',
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: This is also the default value so calling the `react()` plugin without arguments does the same job

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't using nx but had the same problem.

Your `vite.config.js` file must be at the same level of your `package.json`, otherwise the config won't be read and you won't see any warnings, but you'll get the `React is not defined` error.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a `import React from 'react';` import at the top of the component test file fixed it for me